# ASP.Net SQL Text parse HTML

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

Currently I'm busy with a project for school. I was optimizing my FAQ and I want to parse HTML in my TEXT column for my answer. Let me explain it better.

I have my database model, which is this:

```
public class FAQModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

And in my view:

```
<div><p>@item.Answer</p></div>
```

But now HTML (which is in my Answer column) will be like text, so it won't be parsed. Like this is my result:

```
Ga naar <a href="../EmailSub/">deze pagina</a>
```

But I want it to be a link which I can click on. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Html.Raw method will convert the string stored in the db to the DOM elements structure:

@Html.Raw(item.Answer)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the question is, but if you have HTML string in the Answer column in your database, like:
"Ga naar <a href="../EmailSub/">deze pagina</a>"

Then you should use:

```
<div><p>@Html.Raw(item.Answer)</p></div>
```

But I only recommend to use this approach if the answer field in the database is olny filled by administrators, not users, because this is a potential vulnerability called cross-site scripting (XSS)!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can get your goal using `Html.Raw`. Replace

```
<div><p>@item.Answer</p></div>
```

with

```
<div><p>@Html.Raw(item.Answer)</p></div>
```